# Problema com as cores dos Colchetes

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Exemplo do Problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujvn1.png)

Estou com esse bug das cores e já desativei os themes do VSCode e permaneceu igual, apenas resolveu o problema com a criação de outro perfil dentro do VS, gostaria de saber se existe alguma configuração que posso arrumar para resolver

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.